# Degree of a class of map identically zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it true that for any continuous function $u:S^{1}\to\Bbb{R}$ ,the degree of map $exp(2\pi iu):S^{1}\to S^{1}$ is $0$ ?

It seems a little weird to me,and how can I understand the fact intuitively?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, any map $u : S^1 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ has to run backwards over itself in order to close up. Hence, when composing with the projection to $S^1$, the map still runs backwards over itself, and thus has degree zero.

That's not very rigorous, but fortunately there are completely rigorous arguments that are still quite simple.

Namely, for a map $f : S^1 \mapsto S^1$ to have degree zero it is sufficient that $f$ extend over some compact oriented surface whose boundary is identified with the domain $S^1$. But if $f = \exp(2 \pi i u)$ then using that $u$ extends to a map $U : D^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ (because $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible), it follows that $f$ extends to the map $F = \exp(2 \pi i U) : D^2 \to S^1$

Comment: Oh it's quite straight,I should think myself as a point on R as its image,then everything is clear!Thank u so much!

Comment: It is my pleasure.